# DISTINCT not working with hasMany cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to apply DISTINCT query in cakephp 2+ it's working fine but when I BindModel with that model it's not working ?

Here is my code please check it..

```
$this->User->bindModel(
                    array(
                        'hasMany' => array(
                            'UserPreference' => array(
                                'className' => 'UserPreference',
                                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                                'fields' => 'UserPreference.notification_status',
                                'conditions' => array('UserPreference.notification_status' => 1),
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );
            $data = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('app_id NOT ' => '0', 'User.status' => 1), 'fields' => array('DISTINCT User.app_id')));
            pr($data); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

just because I once happened something like this I fix it changing this:

```
$this->User->bindModel(
                    array(
                        'hasMany' => array(
                            'UserPreference' => array(
                                'className' => 'UserPreference',
                                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                                'fields' => 'UserPreference.notification_status',
                                'conditions' => array('UserPreference.notification_status = 1'),
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );
```